# How to convert datetime from "0h:23h" to "1h:24h"?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem with my datetime. In my sql data, I've got a data for time from 1-24h, but in C# datetime I can only model the values from 0h to 23h. How can I convert it to 1-24h?

Thanks in advance!

How can i express to you to understand, my english is not good enough. so sad.
i have a data like this

```
1/1/2010 1:00 20mm
1/1/2010 2:00 30mm
1/1/2010 3:00 50mm
....
1/1/2010 23:00 10mm
1/1/2010 24:00 5mm
2/1/2010 1:00 30mm
2/1/2010 2:00 8mm
```

as you see, there are no 0:00, they write 24:00 insted of 0:00.

Comment: `1-24h`? Are you sure? Is there a hour called `24.00`?

Comment: What do you mean by `1 - 24 h`, can you show some example and datatype used to store this, there is no `24:00` it is `00:00`

Comment: Are you asking how you can update your table to the correct time? Then this is a sql question and you should add your rdbms and table schema.

Comment: What does the data you have look like? Do you have some entries like `2013/Apr/16 - 23:00` that need no transformation, and others like `2013/Apr/16 - 24:00` that must be transformed to `2013/Apr17 - 00:00`? Do you also have times of day strictly over midnight, with the `24` notation, as in `2013/Apr/16 - 24:15` (to be converted to `2013/Apr/17 - 00:15`)? Or maybe you don't have date parts, only hours and minutes?

Comment: in my country, 0h of 2/2/2012 is 24h of 1/2/2012. if you say 0h, everyone understand that is 24h. so, it is my problem.

Comment: 24:00 mean 0:00, but there are no 24:15. in some survey of my, they write 24:00 insted of 0:00.

Comment: What is the datatype of your database time column? Is it just storing times as strings? If so then the answer is to fix the data in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.

```
Datetime.Now.AddHours(-12)
```

It might help you.

Comment: @SonerGönül i am still wondering on the upvotes for the question ! !

Comment: sentil kumar: It might help you getting wrong results, and introducing an additional bugs.

Comment: I have done it in one of my previous case and it works @Quandary.

Comment: I fail to see how modifying the time would help this at all?

Comment: in my country,24:00 mean 0:00, but there are no 24:15. so in some survey of my, they write 24:00 insted of 0:00.

Comment: @sentilkumar: For this to be a good answer you will have to explain how getting the time 12 hours ago from now can possibly help. Are you suggesting that he adds or subtracts 12 hours from the time he has stored? If so how will that actually make a difference - either they are stored as datetimes so shifting them won't actually change the fact they use 24:00 or they aren't in which case you can't easily just take off 12 hours...

Answer (score 0):

0-23h is valid as 0:00 is midnight and 23:59:59 is one second till tomorrow. I'm not sure about how you are getting 1-24 in SQL to be honest, I have always seen the data stored 00-23 in SQL Server.

If you're looking to deal with formatting the data to be displayed then have a look at the following link;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: There is no mention of MySQL in the OP. He states that in his SQL data he's got data for time ("In my sql data, I've got a data for").

Answer (score 0):

Use `ParseMilitaryTime` for this purpose.

Following doccument has all the example and description about the thing you want to do:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/24-hour-time

Comment: Even in U.S. military time like 2401 is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method that does the string formatting for you.

```
string str = System.DateTime.Now.ToMySQLstring();
```

And this is the extension method:

```
namespace System
{


    public static class TimeSpanExtensions
    {


        public static string ToMySQLstring(this DateTime dt)
        {
            int hour = dt.Hour + 1;
            int min = dt.Minute;
            int sec = dt.Second;
            int msec = dt.Millisecond;

            int day = dt.Day;
            int month = dt.Month;
            int year = dt.Year;

            //2009-05-01T14:18:12.430
            return String.Format("{0}-{1:00}-{2:00}T{3:00}:{4:00}:{5:00}.{6:000}", year, month, day, hour, min, sec, msec);
        }


    } // End Class


} // End Namespace
```

Comment: Do you always put your own extension classes in the `System` namespace? I don't think the asker wants one hour added in all cases. For example 17:00 should stay 17:00. It is only when the hour is 00, he wants different formatting. Then you might want to change the date (day, possibly month and year) as well.